# broken ceph dependency with centos7 and epel

Tags: centos7, ceph, epel

Okay, I'm trying to install ceph, using just "yum install ceph" from the epel repositories.

This is what I get:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:python-cephfs-0.80.7-0.8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python-rados = 1:0.80.7
           Available: 1:python-rados-0.94.5-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python-rados = 1:0.94.5-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:ceph-0.80.7-0.8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python-rados = 1:0.80.7
           Available: 1:python-rados-0.94.5-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python-rados = 1:0.94.5-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:ceph-common-0.80.7-0.8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python-rados = 1:0.80.7
           Available: 1:python-rados-0.94.5-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python-rados = 1:0.94.5-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:ceph-common-0.80.7-0.8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python-rbd = 1:0.80.7
           Available: 1:python-rbd-0.94.5-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python-rbd = 1:0.94.5-1.el7
Error: Package: 1:ceph-0.80.7-0.8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python-rbd = 1:0.80.7
           Available: 1:python-rbd-0.94.5-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python-rbd = 1:0.94.5-1.el7
```

Who should I report this too? To the Centos people, the epel people, or the ceph people?

And how can I fix this temporary? I need Ceph today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time this was written, the Ceph packages were being moved out of EPEL because they were being added to RHEL. CentOS had not yet caught up, as there is often a short delay between a RHEL package release and the corresponding CentOS package.

Though, CentOS has chosen to ship Ceph slightly differently than RHEL.

If you're currently reading this question and installing Ceph on CentOS, you should first install the `centos-release-ceph-#######` package corresponding to the version of Ceph you want to run (e.g. `hammer`, `jewel`, `luminous`). You can then `yum install ceph` or upgrade an existing `ceph` to get that version.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old version of the CEPH (0.80), I would suggest to install latest CEPH LTS (luminous) from [CEPH website](http://download.ceph.com/rpm-luminous/el7/).